# Xpage source code duplication

Tags: xpages

In Xpages Sometimes when elements are moved around in the design pane, it gets duplicated (duplication occurs in source code). this was happened during copy paste as well. so I'm getting so many error in my xpages.

- Can anyone explain me why this is happening?
- Is there any solution to prevent this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using 8.5.3?
I encountered this often in eariler versions but haven't seen it in 8.5.3.
Only move elements using cut and paste in source mode, that often helps.

Comment: No I'm using 8.5.2... Let me try 8.5.3